# Search in a list and sum up

Tags: python, list, sum

I have a list containing a bunch of values. I am first trying to find the items with 'MB' inside and then sum up the values. For instance the first one "text:u'3 MB". I want to get this item and sum up the value which in this case will be 3 and do the same with the the next item with "MB" inside.

Code (so far):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import xlrd
xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("E:\usage.xls")

sheet_names = xl_workbook.sheet_names()
print('Sheet Names', sheet_names)

xl_sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
print ('Sheet name: %s' % xl_sheet.name)

liste=[]
sum=0

num_cols = xl_sheet.ncols   # Number of columns
for row_idx in range(0, xl_sheet.nrows):    # Iterate through rows
    for col_idx in range(0, num_cols):  # Iterate through columns
        cell_obj = xl_sheet.cell(row_idx, col_idx)  # Get cell object by row, col
        liste.append(cell_obj)
        #print ('cell_obj: [%s]' % (cell_obj))

for item in liste:
    if "MB" in item:
            print item
```

I am getting this error:

```
     if "MB" in item:
TypeError: argument of type 'Cell' is not iterable
```

List (contains):

```
[xldate:42340.671805555554, text:u'3 MB', empty:'', number:0.0, xldate:42340.501238425924, text:u'12 MB', empty:'', number:0.0, xldate:42340.42820601852, text:u'10 MB', empty:'', number:0.0, xldate:42339.81946759259, text:u'8 MB', empty:'', number:0.0, xldate:42339.55652777778, text:u'6 MB', empty:'', number:0.0, xldate:42339.35625, text:u'10 MB', empty:'', number:0.0, empty:'', empty:'', empty:'', empty:'', empty:'', empty:'', text:u'Totalt:', number:1.01]
```

Comment: The contents of that `liste` is not valid syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `liste` list contains Excel [`Cell` objects](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966#sheet.Cell-class) which are not strings themselves, so you cannot use the `in` operator to check whether the value contains some string. You need to access the string value using the `value` property, but you should only do so for *text cells* as otherwise, `value` will be of a different type:

```
for cell in liste:
    if cell.ctype == 1 and 'MB' in cell.value:
        print cell.value
```

Then, in order to get the number value from the string, you need to extract the number, for example by removing the `MB`:

```
totalMegaBytes = 0
for cell in liste:
    if cell.ctype == 1 and 'MB' in cell.value:
        totalMegaBytes += int(cell.value.replace('MB', ''))

print(totalMegaBytes)
```

Comment: Leave out the `int(value)` in that case, otherwise you will truncate the value (e.g. `23 KB` would be a value of `0.023` and `int()` on that would give you zero).